# Antonym of  "Landed with a thud"?

Tags: antonyms

What would be the antonym of the expression "landed with a thud"?
I've seen it in the context of "a new product landed with a thud, attracting very few customers".

Comment: Until I saw your example, I took this to mean "made a great impact". The examples implies it means "was unimpressive". So it's an [autantonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autantonym) !

Comment: @Colin: "For instance quite, which meant 'clear' or 'free' in Middle English, can mean 'slightly' (quite nice) or completely' (quite beautiful)." ...I always thought "quite nice" meant "very nice".

Comment: There is a well-known phrase *to go over like a lead balloon* (originally a joking response to *how did it go over?*, meaning "how was it received?") - a lead balloon would not "go over" at all, but would land with a thud.  Perhaps most famously, this expression was used to predict the future of a new group being formed after the breakup of the Yardbirds.  They changed the spelling of "lead" so it wouldn't be mispronounced, and they changed the kind of airship... but [Led Zeppelin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin) ended up going over very well indeeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***In this specific context*** I would suggest "landed with a splash" or (better) "made a splash" as an antonym.

However, this is a metaphorical use of "landed with a thud" which means something almost the opposite of what you would expect from the literal meaning.  My suggestions don't apply to more general or literal uses of the phrase.  If you really want to talk about an object *not* making a great deal of noise as it hits the ground, try "landed lightly" or "landed like a cat".

*(Having said that, any cat owner will tell you that cats land with an enormous thud.  Particularly if they are jumping off a high shelf onto your bed.  While you are still in it.)*

Answer (score 6):

I'd understand *"landed with a thud"* in this context as, *"the product was a spectacular flop"*. Antonym would be *"it soared high"*.

Answer (score 2):

"Launched successfully" is the usage I'm used to hearing in Silicon Valley.